# Extract lines separately based on the number of a column in linux

Tags: linux

I want to extract lines for which a certain column has a certain number.
The file is as below.

```
ID Age
1 2
2 5
3 36
4 2
5 29
...
2000 84
```

I would like to extract lines in separate files based on the 2nd column.

```
for Num in {0..84}
do
awk '$2==${Num}' file > out_${Num}
done
```

The above command does not work, but I want to do something like that.
Can anybody please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for num in {0..84}; do co=$(awk -v num="$num" '$2 == num {print $0}' file1|wc -l); if [[ $co > 0 ]]; then awk -v num="$num" '$2 == num {print $0}' file1 >out_$num;fi; done
```

its works fine for this case when tested

Comment: This perfectly worked. Thank you so much, Praveen!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `wc` 85 times, nor `awk` 170 times.
Any restrictions on `$2` other than `$2 >= 0` and `$2 <= 84`? Redirecting print from within `awk`, try (without restrictions)

```
awk 'NR>1 {print > ("out_" $2)}' file
```

If your output files get close to the maximum allowed open files (linux: system parameter OPEN_MAX), you'll need to close the output file after **appending** to them.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion, RudiC. But I wanted to create 84 files, as I wanted to create files for patients with the same age.

Comment: @user10345633: Will `$2` cover all numbers 0 to 84? If not, do you need / wanr empty files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, RudiC. Yes, $2 covers all ages. I do not need empty files.